# Best way to get Sage (I already have python)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, sage

I have and use Python 2.7 on Windows 7. I'm wanting to download Sage, but I already have python and I don't want it to interfere somehow (double installing python, making my current programs run under the wrong installation of python, ect.).

Should I:

- Just install it regularly and call it a day
- ...Or do something else

link to Sage: http://www.sagemath.org/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sage on Windows runs on a virtual machines that uses Linux. As a result, it's almost completely sandboxed from Windows, and will not interfere with your Python installation (or for that matter, any program) in any way.

As a result, since you're only installing a single program -- a virtual machine -- and loading Sage onto it, installing it is completely safe.

Comment: Thanks! So I should use an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox and install Sage in there?

Comment: @Robinson -- you don't even have to do that! You need to three things: download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), download the binary from the Sage website, and then load it into the VM. The sage binary contains a full linux OS pre-loaded with Sage.

Answer (score 1):

Sage has an online IDE which is easier to use than having to install it. Here is the link:
http://www.sagemath.org/